# No Blackberry JRE is installed Message

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to implement a blackberry app. I have already downloaded eclipse and other stuff necessary for blackberry development. Here is what I see when I try to create a new black berry project.

[image]

If I click configure JRE I can see the one that is inside the eclipse folder (I put it there)

[image]

what an I doing wrong? It always says No blackberry JRE is installed. I have also restarted my machine.

UPDATE

[image]

Comment: How did you setup the BlackBerry Development Environment in Eclipse? Did you download and install the **BlackBerry Java Plug-in For Eclipse** or install the plug-in via **Help -> Install New Softwares..**? I have uploaded two screenshot containing JRE configuration from my working **BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse, Version: 1.5.0** installation. Hope these images will help you. Screenshots are here, http://i.stack.imgur.com/knwkD.png, http://i.stack.imgur.com/aZCpq.png.

Comment: Yes I used the Install New Software to install everything. I have updated the question with another screenshot. It says "Install Location does not contain filepreverify.exe".

Comment: I would highly recommend not **adding** the BlackBerry plugin to an existing Eclipse installation.  I would download the complete bundle from BlackBerry.com that installs a fresh version of Eclipse **and** the plugin at the same time.